# Project Euler #12 very long runtime

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, mathematics, time-limit-exceeded

[Project Euler Problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) asks to find the value of the first triangular number to have over 500 divisors, where the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> triangular number is \$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\$.

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural
>   numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be \$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28\$. The first ten terms would be:
>
> ```
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
> ```
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> ```
>  1: 1
>  3: 1,3
>  6: 1,2,3,6
> 10: 1,2,5,10
> 15: 1,3,5,15
> 21: 1,3,7,21
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
> ```
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five
>   divisors.

I have the following code written in C#. I never had the patience to wait for the program to finish but the code shows the right answer because I tried  the example on their website. My code has a very long runtime and I don't know what to do to optimize it. I've waited for like 5-6 minutes on a AMD 4x cores 3.10 GHz and nothing...

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

        Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
        time.Start();

        int trianglenumber = 0;
        int divizori = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++) {
                int tempnumber = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                    tempnumber += j;
                }
                for (int k = 1; k < tempnumber+1; k++) {
                    if (tempnumber % k == 0) {
                        divizori++;
                    }
                }
                if (5 < divizori) {
                    trianglenumber = tempnumber;
                    break;
                }
                divizori = 0;
            }

            time.Stop();

            double timp = time.ElapsedMilliseconds ;

            Console.WriteLine(trianglenumber);
            Console.Write("Runtime: " + timp/1000+ " seconds");
            Console.ReadKey();


    }
```

Comment: Also, there are [faster ways to sum a series](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATP2/ArithSeq.htm) than iteration.

Comment: What the purpose of the test `i < Int32.MaxValue` ?

Comment: Emanuele I don't know the limit so I use the maxvalue of the int32.

I used 130 divisors. With this code I got 2.33 seconds. Installed a isPrime method and if the number is prime, skip it. Got 1.185 seconds on 130 divisors.

Comment: The entire point of the Euler problems is that you should figure them out, not have other people figure them out for you.

Comment: @Guffa I would have thought that the purpose is to learn, which is probably better with help. As long as people explain why doing it one way is better than another then it's okay in my opinion.

Comment: @craftworkgames: Then that would be available on the site. It's not.

Comment: @Guffa fair point.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your algorithm. First note that triangle numbers can be written as:
\$
T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\$
then notice that \$n\$ and \$n+1\$ cannot share a common divisor. So you can find all the divisors of \$T_n\$ just by finding the divisors of \$n\$ and \$n+1\$ (and removing a factor 2) and multiplying them together. This alone should greatly improve your algorithm turning it (the part inside the main loop) from \$O(n^2)\$ to \$O(n)\$.

Then you could make a table of prime number to quickly find the factorization of \$n\$ and \$n+1\$. Once you know the prime factors of \$n\$ you can find the number of all divisors of \$n\$. See, for example, here: http://www.marksmath.com/math/problems/count-div.html

**addendum**

First advice is actually enough. Here is the code (I don't know C#, hope it compiles):

```
static int count_divisors(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int k=1;k<=n;++k) {
    // this loop can be reduced further by noticing that
    // apart from n itself there is no divisor with k*2>n
    if (n % k == 0) count++;
  }
  return count;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
  int last_d = 0; // cache the computation for previous n
  for (int n=0;;++n) {
    int triangular = n*(n+1)/2; // only used for debugging and clarity
    int d; // number of divisors of (n+1) (or (n+1)/2 if (n+1) is even)
    if (n%2==0)
      d = count_divisors(n+1);
    else
      d = count_divisors((n+1)/2); // n+1 is even                               
    // # of divisors of n * (n+1)/2 is the product of divisors
    // since two consecutive numbers do not share any divisor (apart from 1)
    int total = d*last_d;
    if (total>500) {
      Console.WriteLine("found: " + triangular);
      break;
    }
    last_d = d; // cache the computation
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the part from "  So you can find all the divisors of Tn just by finding the divisors of n and n+1 (and removing a factor 2). This alone should greatly improve you.... "

Comment: made this: http://pastebin.com/RmQWJEb4 , guess what, even slower

Comment: I have added the code. Gives 76576500 as solution.

Comment: Why are you answering a C# question with C code?? No they are nowhere near similar enough for this sort of thing.

Comment: Yeah, C is very different from C#... Thanks for trying to answering me tho'.

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't know C#... and cannot compile it. So I made a complete C source to test it. But I believe that modifications are minimal. Also the question here is about algorithms, not language.

Comment: While that may actually be true given you know both languages it is considered bad review style mostly. Additionally i doubt that the complexity is actually $O(n^4)$

Comment: I have converted the code from C to C# (hopefully)

Comment: @Vogel612 I corrected the code complexity assertion. In the main loop of the OP code, one has tempnumber=\$O(i^2)\$ and hence the iteration in k is \$O(i^2)\$. While in my code it is O(n).

Comment: That's definitely better, but there's still work to do. Why did you chose an "infinte" for-loop over OP's approach? How does your algo work in detail?

Comment: @Vogel612 the condition `i < Int32.MaxValue` makes no sense. The for loop is broken as soon as the solution is found.

Comment: I know, but explain that in your answer..